# Error android SurfaceFlinger

Tags: android, surfaceflinger

I have this error message:

SurfaceFlinger translucent=0 isOpaque=1 isExternalDisplayLayer=0 isExternalBlockLayer0

i'm using android 4.1.1

I'm not capable to say which part of my code is generating this message

I would like to know if someone had the same message, it's meaning and potentially the way to solve this

issue.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am also getting this error. I believe it is to do with Samsung's TouchWiz and not part of your code, are you running it on a Samsung device?

Comment: yes, samsung Galaxy tab 2,
do you have any idea how solve it?

Comment: Afraid not, all the Galaxy Tabs I use throw this error constantly into logcat. I just filter it out.

Comment: ok thanks :) I think if it's specific to Samsung devices a filtering will be enough.

Comment: This is not devise dependent problem

Comment: It was very much a device dependent problem when the question was asked @VishalGolakiya - but thanks for the downvote :)