# Permission Denial: SurfaceFlinger did not recognize request code: 1128 - Unity, Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, surfaceflinger

I'm working on a 2D Android game in Unity.
I have started receiving this message in Logcat - repeating all the time:

*Error SurfaceFlinger: Permission Denial: SurfaceFlinger did not recognize request code: 1128*

Do you have any idea what might be causing this behavior?
Thank you

Comment: When this has come up before on SO, the answer has basically just been to ignore the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527726/error-android-surfaceflinger Is it impeding your functionality?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm concerned about battery life and performance of the game on lower end devices since the error keeps throwing pretty fast and seems like garbage collector has a lot of work than too.